# Ruby dotenv gem not loading .env file

Tags: ruby

I have the both the `dotenv` and `dotenv-rails` gem installed in my project. When I run the rails console I can type:

```
2.4.0 :001 > ENV["DATABASE_NAME"]
 => "portfolio_site_development"
```

However my problem arises with Ruby, when in a Ruby file or the irb terminal when I call:

```
2.4.0 :001 > ENV["DATABASE_NAME"]
 => nil
```

I am requiring `dotenv` in my Ruby file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you call `Dotenv.load` as in the README examples? The Rails gem probably does so for you, but if you're using plain Ruby you'll have to actually load it. https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#sinatra-or-plain-ol-ruby

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you for the fast reply, I did call Dotenv.load unfortunately :( I have it at the very top: http://imgur.com/SLXJmLh

Comment: What is the name of your `.env` file? In Rails you're probably using environment-specific files like `.env.development` but by default `Dotenv.load` will read a file called `.env`

Comment: In IRB, a simple `require 'dotenv'; Dotenv.load` results in a Hash of the variables defined in `./.env`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The `.env` file is called `.env` and is located directly at the root `/.env`. Is that where it is supposed to be in ruby? Here is the current file structure: http://imgur.com/JhafycL

Comment: why do you have dotenv and dotenv-rails installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. While this used to work, I guess a recent update of `dotenv` has changed things.

Because my ruby script is located in `./lib/scripts/script.rb` I needed to call `Dotenv.load("../../.env")` so that it would point it to my `.env` file in the root of the project structure.

Comment: More recent changes let you do `require 'dotenv/load'`